# Does the dependent clause refer to the intended antecedent in this sentence?

Tags: subordinate-clauses

> The question hung in the room we were in, trembling in the cold.

Is the antecedent (in the broader sense) of the dependent clause 'we' or 'the question' here? How would you improve the sentence, given that it needs to start with 'The question..."?

Comment: The two assertions seem too disparate to join in a single sentence, lex,  so 'what sounds natural' hardly works as a test here. << 'We stood there most uncomfortably, trembling in the cold. The question hung in the room.' >> is the style I'd choose. Artificial constraints (the single sentence needs to start with "The question") make this an unsuitable question for ELU.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth "Artificial constraints (the single sentence needs to start with "The question") make this an unsuitable question for ELU." <--- Stop making things up!

Comment: @Araucaria 'How would you improve the sentence, given that it needs to start with "The question" ' smacks of 'How would you cross the Atlantic, given that you must not fly or sail?' The question is predicated on a poor example IMO. Misplaced modifiers and the over-prescriptiveness of never accepting them has been adequately dealt with here before.

Comment: If the question is not trembling: *The question hung in the room where we were trembling in the cold.*

Comment: The first dependent clause in the sentence is _we were in_; it's a restrictive relative clause and modifies _room_. As for _we_ vs _question_, it's ambiguous; the sentence could be pronounced (differently) with different meanings. What does it sound like? All written sentences are inherently ambiguous.

Comment: If the question is trembling, “The question hung in the room we were in, where it trembled in the cold.”

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The adjunct (or 'adverbial')  *trembling in the cold* is ambiguous in this position, as it could belong to the main clause:

1. *The question hung in the room we were in*

Or it could belong to the subordinate relative clause, which we can represent like this:

2. *we were in <s>the room</s>*

If we interpret it as belonging to the main clause, then it could momentarily give rise to the following interpretation, where I have removed the relative clause *we were in*:

3. *The question hung in the room, trembling in the cold*.

This is clearly not what the Original Poster desires. Some traditional grammarians might argue that if the adjunct is in the man clause, this is the only correct interpretation of the grammar because, it is alleged, the understood subject of the adjunct must be the same as the subject of the main clause. However, as  research now shows, this kind of stipulation is too strict and does not affect what the best writers of English have traditionally done. How we interpret the subject of such adjuncts is complex [see Jim Donaldson's PhD thesis: [*Control in free adjuncts: the 'dangling modifier' in English* (2021)](https://era.ed.ac.uk/bitstream/handle/1842/37779/Donaldson2021.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y), or [his abstract, here](https://era.ed.ac.uk/handle/1842/37779)]. Our interpretation takes place incrementally and depends on many factors. However, although we cannot say that they are ungrammatical,  what we *can* definitively say is that such  participle-clause adjuncts constitute bad writing if they are ambiguous or if they lead the reader in the wrong direction so that they have to backtrack and reread in order to understand the sentence. More on this in a second.

The second possibility here, of course, is that the adjunct belongs to the relative clause which gives it the following interpretation:

5. *the room [we were in <s>the room</s> , trembling in the cold].*

There is no doubt that the relative clause shown in (5) is perfectly grammatical according to traditional grammatical orthodoxy. The intended subject of *trembling in the room* is the same as the subject of the clause it is modifying: *we*.

So there is nothing wrong with the grammar of the Original Poster's sentence. Does this mean it's ok? No! We noted above that the real crime, when it comes to participle adjuncts such as these, is when the adjunct makes the reader misunderstand or stumble a bit in their reading. As currently written, this is what seems to happen here, somewhat. This is a matter of style and good writing, and not grammaticality. But it is till an important matter!

In my opinion, there are two things that could be done. If we wish to stick closely with the Original Poster's wording, we can make the intended reading more salient, and the unintended one less so, by including the subordinator (read 'subordinating conjunction') *that*. This has the effect of more clearly delineating the relative clause from the clause it modifies:

6. *The question hung in the room **that** we were in, trembling in the cold.*

In my opinion this does not tend to cause the reader stumble so much.

However, the OP also asked whether there was a better phrasing of the sentence. Again, also an opinion about style, not a fact about grammar, I have an editorial suggestion. The relative clause *we were in* really provides no information and adds no interest for the reader.  It will be perfectly clear to any reader that the question was delivered in the same room as the people who heard it! It is very unlikely that the question hung around in a room that its audience  weren't in!

For this reason, it might be better to get rid of the relative clause altogether, and put the trembling information in a finite clause adjunct with a tensed verb, instead of using an *-ing* participle adjunct. We can do this using the preposition (read 'subordinating conjunction') *as*. This captures the simultaneity of the hanging around and the trembling in the same way that a participle adjunct would:

7. *The question hung in the room as we trembled in the cold.*

Comment: (7) makes it sound like the question was in the room and the people were in the cold (perhaps outdoors); I don’t sense a cold room containing a question and people here.

Answer (score 0):

> trembling in the cold

is a non-finite clause so it does not have a subject. However, the agent of ***trembling*** is logically ***we***, though grammatically it is supposed to modify the subject of the main clause (*the question*). So the sentence is badly written, as grammar does not convey the meaning it is supposed to convey.

Maybe a better way to formulate it would be:

> The question hung in the room ***and*** we were standing/sitting there, trembling in the cold.

By adding AND, the relative clause in your example (*we were in*), becomes an independent clause here and its subject can therefore claim the agency of *trembling*.

But from your post it is not clear if the author of the sentence did intend to use a metaphor about the question "trembling in the cold". If that is the case, I gather my answer would be different.

Comment: A free adjunct like *trembling in the cold* can belong to a main clause or a subordinate content clause or a relative clause. It's perfectly grammatical, though not very graceful, for it to be an adjunct within the relative  clause _we were in [the room] trembling in the cold_, where [the room] represents the gap anaphorically linked to, and interpreted as, _the room_. And in that case the subject of the adjunct and its matrix clause are the same.